# randomly fade images in and out

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I want to fade in and out some images,randomly from when the page loads until closed.
What I have so for.
css

```
#block{position:relative;top:100px;left:100px;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="block">
<img src="images/block/blockone.jpg"width="95"height="95">
<img src="images/block/blocktwo.jpg"width="95"height="95">
//Five images as such
</div>
```

The script

```
function random(n){
return Math.floor(Math.random()*n);
var transition_time=500;
var waiting_time=500;
var images=$('div#block img');
var n=images.length;
var current=random(n);
images.hide();
images.eq(current).show();
var interval_id=setInterval(function(){
images.eq(current).fadeOut(transition_time,function(){current=random(n);
images.eq(current).fadeIn(transition_time);
});
},2*transition_time+waiting_time);
```

It is not working and I' really like to hear your advice

Answer (score 4):

There is a syntax error in the code, also move the code under dom ready hadnler

```
jQuery(function(){
    function random(n) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
    }// this was missing
    var transition_time = 500;
    var waiting_time = 500;
    var images = $('div#block img').hide();
    var n = images.length;
    var current = random(n);
    images.hide();
    images.eq(current).show();

    var interval_id = setInterval(function () {
        images.eq(current).fadeOut(transition_time, function () {
            current = random(n);
            images.eq(current).fadeIn(transition_time);
        });
    }, 2 * transition_time + waiting_time);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qq68m/)